# java logical not operator

Tags: java, logical-operators

This is a silly question but I just want to understand it clearly before I start using it.

```
if (!ServiceHelpers.DISCOVER) {
  ServiceHelpers.discover(MainActivity.this, peerList);
}
```

I would like to know what `!ServiceHelpers.DISCOVER` mean?

Answer (score 3):

`!` operator inverts the value of a `boolean`.

In this case the `boolean` is `ServiceHelpers.DISCOVER`.

If it's value is `true` the `!` operator will make it `false` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

**! (logical not)**

> Called Logical NOT Operator. Use to reverses the logical state of its
>   operand. If a condition is true then Logical NOT operator will make
>   false.

From [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html),

> !Logical complement operator;
>
> inverts the value of a boolean

```
if (!ServiceHelpers.DISCOVER)
```

is same as

```
if( Not True)
```

meaning, `ServiceHelpers.DISCOVER` `is not True the enter inside If`

Answer (score 0):

! is a logical not operator in java.

Code:

```
 boolean a = true; // --> variable 
   if(! a)
   {
      System.out.println("Not A i.e. A if false");
   }
```

if a = true, then (!a) evaluates to (not a) i.e (not true) i.e (false) and if condition is false, then it doesn't evalutes the if condition.