# How to check "not in" in java?

Tags: java

I used to write something like this in Python

```
if name not in data:
    do something
else:
    print("that name is already taken")
```

and now I am learning Java and I have no idea to write the "not in" logical in Java.

Comment: [so] is not the place for learning the basic syntax of a language.

Comment: Assuming that `data` in a `List` then use `contains`

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932074/java-logical-not-operator).

Comment: Start from the basic of the [Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html)

Comment: Also depends on the type of `data`.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=not+java&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:he-IL:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=zUm7Wu3ZH7T08Ae3op2oCQ&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: Simple search gave me 360 million results.

Comment: @guy, the question is not about `not`, it's about `contains`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Clearly it is about both.

Comment: @khelwood "clearly" is a bit of an overstatement, IMHO. Anyway I should have phrased my comment better. It is not *only* about "not"

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yeah, I missed the place of the quotation marks. Still very simple search though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i check if an Array List contains a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358590/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-list-contains-a-certain-string)

Comment: Is `data` a list? An array? A String? Different types in Java have different methods for this kind of thing.

Comment: What is data? Any collection?

Answer (score 1):

is java for say **NOT** you just need add an **!** in your condition. So you can do that :

```
if (!data.contains(name)){
    //data contain name
}else{
    //data dont contain name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The NOT operator in java is `!`

```
if (!data.contains(name)) {
    do something;
} else {
    System.out.println("that name is already taken");
}
```

Comment: I removed your addendum as it should have been a comment, not part of your answer. If others think it should have stayed there, feel free to revert it.

Comment: If it was helpful, accept the answer. And for the future:  Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you downvote? If you don't agree with the question, then downvote it. But not a correct answer.